# Woocommerce, ordering products by default on shortcode pages

Tags: shortcode, plugins, sort

In my woocommerce store I have a Sale Products page. In this page I use the shortcode to display the products on sale

```
[sale_products per_page="40" columns="3"]
```

In the store the products are ordered according to their position in a list in the backend (accessible via the Products->sort products link). This sorts them on normal category pages but on a shortcode page they are sorted by title. I know there is an `orderby` attribute I can add but is there an argument that will achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to order by `menu_order` like this:

```
[sale_products per_page="40" columns="3" orderby="menu_order"]
```

if the corresponding callback is using `WP_Query()` to query the products.

Comment: There is a documentation for [Woocommerce Shortcodes](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/). Available args are listed for each shortcode, the `[sale_products]` shortcode has: `per_page`, `columns`, `orderby` and `order`. @harryg